# I need help Installing a tar.gz file

Tags: software-installation

I've got Flash 11.2 beta in a tar.gz file. I'm new to Linux and I don't know what I'm doing. How can I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the old flash (if necessary)

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
```

Extract the contents

```
tar xvf flashplayer11-2_p3_install_lin_32_122011.tar.gz
```

Copy the library

```
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

Restart firefox

Comment: You are most welcome, reverse those steps if the beta is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

The `.tar.gz` part of the filename says that the file is a "Tape ARchive" compressed with `gzip`. `man tar` should help.

To view the contents of the archive:

```
tar tzvf <filename>.tar.gz
```

And, to extract the files into the current directory:

```
tar xzvf <filename>.tar.gz
```

Then, read the files in the extracted directory named in all uppercase, probably called `INSTALL`, `README*`, `LICENSE`, etc, and follow the directions contained in them.

If you would specify the file you're trying to install, you probably could get more detailed help.

Comment: this is the name of the file flashplayer11-2_p3_install_lin_32_122011.tar.gz

Comment: The flash player is distributed as a binary.